# No /sys/module/hid_apple directory

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules

In my `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`, I have added the `hid_apple` module, see the output of `head /etc/mkinitcpio.conf` below:

```
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES=(usbhid xhci_hcd)
MODULES=(nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm hid_apple)

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
```

I then re-generated my `initramfs` by doing `sudo mkinitcpio --config /etc/mkinitcpio.conf --generate /boot/initramfs-custom.img`

Finally I rebooted.

However, I still don't see a `/sys/module/hid_apple` directory! What am I missing?

Here is the output of `ls /sys/module/ | grep hid`:

```
~ ❯ ls /sys/module/ | grep hid                                                                                                                                  18:17:32
hid
hid_logitech_dj
hid_logitech_hidpp
mac_hid
usbhid
~ ❯
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE:**

I tried telcoM's suggestion. I manually loaded the `hid_apple` module via `sudo modprobe hid_apple`.

I then did `lsmod` and at the very top, and got the following:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
hid_apple              24576  0
xt_conntrack           12288  1
xt_MASQUERADE          16384  1
nf_conntrack_netlink    61440  0
```

To find out about any dependencies, I ran `sudo modprobe -v hid_apple` ([learnt about that -v flag here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_Kernel_Modules/)) but it didn't list anything, so I guess there are no dependencies!?

Also to double check `hid_apple` was setup, I ran:

```
~ ❯ sudo lsinitcpio /boot/initramfs-custom.img | grep apple                                                                                 
usr/lib/modules/6.6.1-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-apple.ko
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hid_apple` module must have failed to load. Perhaps it depends on some other module that is not loaded yet at that point?

You should see a relevant error message in `dmesg` listing.

If possible, note the topmost module in the `lsmod` listing, then load the `hid_apple` module manually, then run `lsmod` again and note all the modules added as a result. Then make sure all those modules are included in your `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`, ideally in the appropriate order.